# Get derivative with square root in the denominator

Tags: derivatives

Given:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{3}{\sqrt{2x^7}} \\
\\
\frac{df}{dx} &=
\end{align}$$

The expected answer is:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{3}{\sqrt{2x^7}} \\
\\
\frac{df}{dx} &= -\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4x\sqrt{x^7}}
\end{align}$$

But what steps would I need to take to that answer?

Comment: use $f(x)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2x^7}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}x^{\frac{7}{2}}}$

Comment: Consider the derivative of $kx^n$, where $n = \displaystyle \frac{-7}{2}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would use the chain rule. Rewrite the function as:

$$f(x) = 3(2x^7)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Using the chain rule:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = -\frac{1}{2} *3(2x^7)^{-\frac{3}{2}} * 14x^6$$

$$\frac{df}{dx} = -\frac{21x^6}{2^\frac{3}{2} x^\frac{21}{2}}$$

$$\frac{df}{dx} = -\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}x^\frac{9}{2}}$$

$$\frac{df}{dx} = -\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4x^\frac{9}{2}}$$
$$\frac{df}{dx} = -\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4x \sqrt{x^7}}$$

This is really really weird simplification, like why write $x^\frac{9}{2}$ as $x\sqrt{x^7}$ instead of $\sqrt{x^9}$? Idk but that's how it was done.

Comment: so it could also be:
$$-\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4x\sqrt{x^9}}$$
?

Comment: @DylanWeijgertze Oh no, that's not the same. $\sqrt{x^7} = x^\frac{7}{2}$ and when you multiply the same variable, the exponents add: $x^3 * x^2 = x^5$, and $x^1 * x^\frac{7}{2} = x^\frac{9}{2} = \sqrt{x^9}$. So $x \sqrt{x^9} = \sqrt{x^{11}}$.

Comment: @DylanWeijgertze Does that make more sense?

Comment: Oh so it would be $$-\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4\sqrt{x^9}}$$ instead of 

 $$-\frac{21\sqrt{2}}{4x\sqrt{x^7}}$$

Comment: @DylanWeijgertze Yes those two equations are identical. If you wanna check plug them both into a graphing calculator and you'll see there is no difference between them.